# Browser Downloading Files Instead of Opening Them

Tags: linux, php

My browser is downloading PHP files instead of opening them.

If I type into the browser:

```
mysite.com:9000/demo/Test.php
```

It will download the file.

However, if I use this for another PHP file then it shows the page.

```
mysite.com/Test2.php
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This probably has a straightforward answer (though I can't tell from the information provided); but would be better off on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) (or *possibly* [webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if it's a simple answer)

Comment: What server are you running on port 9000? Normally a web server runs on port 80 which is the default being used when you do `mysite.com/Test2.php` so what is running on port 9000?

Answer (score 1):

I think your web server is not configured to "interpret" the php files on port 9000, but only on defaut port (80).

Which webserver do you use ? Apache 2 ?

Comment: Hi Matthieu, welcome to Super User! Can you give more details to your answer? A [good answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) addresses the question- OP is looking for how to fix the problem. See [How to write a good answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) for more guidance.